# How to split a list into multiple lists based on elements?

Tags: list, split

I have a file which has multiple file in it. Multiple files have excel files. I could put them on a list

```
excel_files = []
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(bugra_path):
    for filename in files:
        if filename == 'desktop.ini': continue
        excel_files.append(filename)
```

The output is like that:

```
['2019-11-kudup.xlsx', '2019-12-kudup.xlsx', '2019-11-kur.xlsx', '2019-12-kur.xlsx', '2019-11-bilateral_buys.xlsx', '2019-12-bilateral_buys.xlsx', '2019-11-bilateral_sells.xlsx', '2019-12-bilateral_sells.xlsx', '2019-11-dam_buys.xlsx', '2019-12-dam_buys.xlsx', '2019-11-dam_sells.xlsx', '2019-12-dam_sells.xlsx', '2019-11-productions.xlsx', '2019-12-productions.xlsx', '2019-11-ptf_smf.xlsx', '2019-12-ptf_smf.xlsx']
```

However, this not enough for me, I want to split this list into multiple lists based on its element names. I mean want to achieve this:

```
kudup_list = ['2019-11-kudup.xlsx', '2019-12-kudup.xlsx']
kur_list = ['2019-11-kur.xlsx', '2019-12-kur.xlsx']
bilateral_buys_list = ['2019-11-bilateral_buys.xlsx', '2019-12-bilateral_buys.xlsx']
bilateral_sells_list = ['2019-11-bilateral_sells.xlsx', '2019-12-bilateral_sells.xlsx']
dam_buys_list = ['2019-11-dam_buys.xlsx', '2019-12-dam_buys.xlsx']
dam_sells_list = ['2019-11-dam_sells.xlsx', '2019-12-dam_sells.xlsx']
productions_list = ['2019-11-productions.xlsx', '2019-12-productions.xlsx']
ptf_smf_list = ['2019-11-ptf_smf.xlsx', '2019-12-ptf_smf.xlsx']
```

How can I get this output?

Comment: Please add some information about the programming language you are using, and also show what you've tried to achieve

Comment: I always use python :)

Comment: Actually, I thought the pandas would be redundant. @jezrael